# angularJs - won't show data until user types in search field

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, firebase

Final Solution?  It looks like I had my routing and controllers a little confused.  I had my routing in a file with my controller module.  I moved my routeProvider into the main module, like in the tutorial example.  My controller and my routeProvider where under the same module.  Maybe that was confusing everything.  So now I have the controller in it's own module, and the routeProvider is under the main module.  That seems to have fixed the problem without needing to initialize the search field to force the bindings to update the data.

Update:
The solution to showing my data at the time the page loads was to use an ***older version*** of angularJs, or use `ng-Init` and initialize the search field to a blank space.

I'm getting JSON data from the firebase website to update a table.  I have a search field that works.  The data will not display in the table until I type something into the search field.  I don't know why the data won't just display in the table as soon as the controller is done getting the data.

Note:  The link to the backend data is now removed, I don't want to keep that database file there indefinitely.

Here is the link to the jsFiddle code:
[Last Version jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Blueprinter/qKH2z/37/)

Here is code for the controller.

```
'use strict';
/* App Module */
// Create the module named 'testApp'
var testApp = angular.module('theTestApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'testServices'
]);

'use strict';
/* Services */

var testServices = angular.module('testServices', []);

testServices.controller('CommonController',
    // function($scope, $http, $route) {
    function($scope, $http) {
    //access the customInput property using $route.current
    //var dbKey = $route.current.customInput;
    var dbKey = 'test-a-db-12345';
    var urlToDb = 'https://' + dbKey + '.firebaseio.com/rows/.json';
    $http.get(urlToDb).success(function(data) {
    $scope.UsedItems = data;
    });

});
```

How do I get the data to display as soon as it's loaded?

Update 1: I'm assuming that the data is already there, but the event of typing something into the search field triggers the filter, and then the data shows up.  It shows up filtered.

Update 2: I'm reading about `$Watch` There is constantly and event loop listening for events.  When a key is pressed in the search box, the bindings `{{name}}` get updated if something has changed.  In this case, the content of the search input field was changed.  So the issue seems to have something to do with when the bindings get updated, not whether the data is getting retrieved.

Update 3:
This version of the code runs.  It loads the data when the page is rendered.  Here is a working example in jsBins.

Update 4:
As of angularJs version 1.2.0 the behavior changes.  Versions 1.0.8, 1.0.7 will instantly display my data when the page loads, 1.2.0 will NOT!  I just happened to be using jsBins which uses 1.0.7, and it started working.  Didn't know why until I started comparing the differences.  Hopefully, there is a way to make it work in newer versions.

[jsBins Working Example](http://jsbin.com/araTUyO/2/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: It would be better if your controller code was part of your fiddle.

Comment: I put a complete working copy into jsBins.  [jsBins working code](http://jsbin.com/araTUyO/2/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Consider using AngularFire if you're combining Firebase with Angular: http://angularfire.com/

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `theSearch.Txt` is empty. And you are filtering by that. My guess is that Angular at that moment decides to not let anything through and thus doesn't display anything.

**What you should do:**

Initialize the variable with a space filled string. (i.e. ' ')

Here is a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qKH2z/29/embedded/result/).

I used ngInit here. But that is because you decided to link?? the controller instead of putting it into a script tag. I suggest that next time you rather take the additional effort into pasting it in, as  using the `ngInit` directive makes me feel like using `eval`.

Comment: That works, adding:  ng-init="theSearch.Txt = ' '"  to the DIV element.

Comment: There is a problem with initializing the search field with a blank space in order to get the data bindings to update.  The user probably won't realize that there is a blank space there, and if the user doesn't delete that blank space after doing a search, the original data does not go back to displaying all of the records.

Comment: In the documentation, in red letters, it states that controllers should be used to initialize values on a scope, and not ng-init.  This is a quote, "The only appropriate use of ngInit is for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat"  [angularjs documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngInit)

Comment: Even though ng-init did force the data bindings to update, I found the problem, and did not need to use the ng-init solution.  For some reason, the firebase database that I was using was breaking the update.  I'm wondering if it had to do with to many hyphens in the name?  Also, I'm using a routeProvider to trigger a controller, and the routeProvider was in the wrong .js file.

Comment: I did tell you that in my answer.

Comment: You want some more points?  I really don't care how many points anyone has or doesn't have, and the point system on this site is a pathetic joke.  I put a lot of time into updating my progress, hoping that it might help someone in the future.  That's my goal.

Comment: I do not care about the points, but the idea of any stackexchange site is to ask a question and get back an answer. Since this was your first question and you left a comment telling how it worked for you but did not accept any answer or posted your own I asked you to do that.

Comment: If you managed to find another answer which is cleaner please do post it (and accept it afterwards). After all you made it clear that my answer telling you initialize a variable was not sufficient for your problem and you have found your own but posted it in the comments of my answer.

Comment: I had a situation where I posted something, and answered my own question, and got 15 down votes.  That's why I'm not posting an answer outside of the original post.  I guess there is a concern by some, that people will post a question that they already know the answer to, answer it, then vote their answer as the correct one just to get some points.  Even if someone did that, I don't care, if it's good information.  I got some criticism from a few idiots who thought I was just trying to promote myself.  So that's why I won't answer my own question outside of the original post.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$scope.$apply(function(){
    $scope.UsedItems=data;
}
```

Comment: useless. The success function of $http is already called by Angular in $apply.